# Updating List Item using REST listdata.svc results in internal error 500 http response

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, rest

I created an ASP.NET web application that allows the user to modify data that is stored in SharePoint I rather not go into the reasons why this application was created but focus more on why doesn't the listdata.svc allow me to update a task item that was created by a workflow collect data from user action.

1. The workflow creates the item.

I collect the item and update the item using the below code. This is not an OOTB approval workflow that is just the name I used. When I get to save changes I received the following error code http 500 an error occurred while processing this request.

```
  Dim getApprovalItem As ExpenseApprovalRuleBasedTasksItem = spContext.ExpenseApprovalRuleBasedTasks.Where(Function(i) i.Id = Pam.ApprovalItemID).FirstOrDefault

                If String.IsNullOrEmpty(getApprovalItem.AuditorApprovalValue) Then

                    getApprovalItem.AuditingComments = approvalComments

                    Select Case approvalDecision
                        Case "Approved"
                            getApprovalItem.AuditorApproval = ExpenseApprovalRuleBasedTasksAuditorApprovalValue.CreateExpenseApprovalRuleBasedTasksAuditorApprovalValue("Approved")
                            getApprovalItem.AuditorApprovalValue = "Approved"

                        Case "Rejected"
                            getApprovalItem.AuditorApproval = ExpenseApprovalRuleBasedTasksAuditorApprovalValue.CreateExpenseApprovalRuleBasedTasksAuditorApprovalValue("Rejected")
                            getApprovalItem.AuditorApprovalValue = "Rejected"
                    End Select

                    getApprovalItem.Outcome = "Completed"

                    getApprovalItem.Status = ExpenseApprovalRuleBasedTasksStatusValue.CreateExpenseApprovalRuleBasedTasksStatusValue("Completed")
                    getApprovalItem.StatusValue = "Completed"

                    getApprovalItem.Complete = True

                    spContext.UpdateObject(getApprovalItem)

                    spContext.SaveChanges()

                End If
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this server side using the workflow om.

```
  Using myweb = New SPSite("sharepoint-site")

        Using subWeb As SPWeb = myweb.OpenWeb()

            Dim approvalList As SPList = subWeb.Lists("Expense Task Review")

            Dim expenseItem As SPListItem = approvalList.Items.GetItemById(relatedItemId)

            If Not expenseItem Is Nothing Then

                For Each wfTaskItem As Microsoft.SharePoint.Workflow.SPWorkflowTask In expenseItem.Tasks

                    If wfTaskItem.ID = approvalItemID Then

                        Dim ht = New Hashtable

                        subWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = True

                        ht(SPBuiltInFieldId.Completed) = "TRUE"

                        ht(SPBuiltInFieldId.PercentComplete) = 1

                        ht(SPBuiltInFieldId.TaskStatus) = SPResource.GetString(New CultureInfo(CType(wfTaskItem.Web.Language, Integer), False), "WorkflowTaskStatusComplete", New Object() {})

                        ht(SPBuiltInFieldId.FormData) = Microsoft.SharePoint.Workflow.SPWorkflowStatus.Completed

                        Microsoft.SharePoint.Workflow.SPWorkflowTask.AlterTask(wfTaskItem, ht, True)

                        'wfTaskItem(SPBuiltInFieldId.WorkflowVersion) = 1

                        wfTaskItem.Web.Update()

                        Return True

                    End If

                Next

            End If

            Return False

        End Using

    End Using
```